# Retrofit and Spotify API: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, json, retrofit, spotify, retrofit2

There are several questions on stackoverflow that are just like mine, but I haven't been able to solve my issue. The error is as stated in the title. I'm working with the Spotify API to get the [current user's profile](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-current-users-profile/). I feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding with what's going on.

Here's what I have in my main activity:

```
    Gson gson1 = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    Retrofit retrofit1 = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ENDPOINT_ACCOUNTS)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson1))
            .build();

    SpotifyAPI spotifyAPI = retrofit1.create(SpotifyAPI.class);
    Call<User> call1 = spotifyAPI.getUserData("Authorization: Bearer " + sp.getString("accessCode", "DEFAULT"));

    call1.enqueue(new Callback<User> () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            ... 
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Here is my interface:

```
String ENDPOINT_V1 = "https://api.spotify.com/";
@GET("/v1/me")
Call<User> getUserData(@Header("Authorization") String authorization);
```

And here is my User class:

```
public class User {
    String id;

    public String toString() {
       return(id);
    }
}
```

OnFailure() is being triggered, spitting out the error message in the title. If I substitute all instances of User with ResponseBody, the call succeeds with a status code of 200. But the contents of response is not at all what I want. Please let me know if there is more information I can provide. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my base URL was wrong. Works like a charm now. Thanks for looking this through.